# Operator overloading in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading, extension-function

String division using operator overloading in `Kotlin`, please help me to complete this code. No change can be made in main function. 
Find common from both string like `a=aabcc b=abdec answer=abc` (unique common characters)

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) 
{
      val a:String = readLine()!!

      val b:String = readLine()!!

      val result = a/b

      println(result)
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Operators can be defined externaly, just like extension functions:

```kotlin
operator fun String.div(other: String): String {
    // Put your implementation here
}
```

As for the implementation: you should probably do your assignment yourself.

Comment: can someone answer this

Comment: @AMIT, answer what?